# .urbanairship. Skipped invalid apid when try the test push

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

Today i integrate the urbanairship to my android app following this guide,http://urbanairship.com/docs/getting_started_android_push.html. after completing the guide i tried to send the test push notification and i got the following error message

```
ERROR   Skipped invalid apids: 2037c72a-065d-46e1-8761-6acb88cf 8ed3 
Original Message: {"android": {"alert": "Hello from Urban Airship!"}, "apids": ["2037c72a-065d-46e1-8761-6acb88cf8ed3"]}
follwoing details on my airshipconfig.properties file
```

transport = helium
com.urbanairship.Logger.logLevel = Log.VERBOSE;

Please advice me how to fix this issue,

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

might help for some one

I noticed this log message on the log cat:

WARN/Push Sample - UALib(2429): This application is in a holding pattern, most likely because your 
account does not have Helium access. To sign up for a free trial, visit https://go.urbanairship.com/apps/free-trial/. 
Once granted permission, you should fully uninstall the app before testing again, in order to clear this flag.

i found the following link on the support center.
https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/91035-about-the-helium-holding-pattern

as they said i make the account to trial,then every thing work fine. now im getting the notifications ;)